# Testing file locking

Tags: bash, shell-script, concurrency, flock

I have a script which locks a file to avoid concurrent access to it, How can I execute this same script from two different terminals synchronously, to check if it works?

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

(
  flock -xn 200
  trap 'rm /tmp/test_lock.txt' 0
  RETVAL=$?
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo $RETVAL
    echo  "file already removed"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "locked and removed"
  fi
) 200>/tmp/test_lock.txt
```

Comment: Note `$?` in your code expands to the exit status of `trap`. I guess this is not what you want.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute them *synchronously*, but by placing a `sleep 60` inside the bracketed lock section you can demonstrate to yourself that only one instance can run simultaneously (at the same time). Or not.

---

You'll notice that what you have does not work. This is because you delete the lock file, which means that any new process trying to obtain the lock does so on a different file to the one that already holds the lock.

Comment: I tried, they both get inside the "sleep" block

Comment: Then what you have doesn't work

Comment: @Rob I've added an explanation for you